# How to toggle microphone on and off using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if there is a way to use python to mute and microphone? I am working on a project that requires the Microphone setting to be set to "Listen to this device". However, to prevent the Microphone from picking up unwanted noise from a TV or radio, I need a way to toggle between Mute and Unmute through a python script.

Comment: Operating system? For Linux, audio system (eg. PulseAudio, ALSA, OSS)? For things like audio it typically goes "What library/package does the system you need to run on use for this?" and then "Is there a Python API binding or wrapper for that library/package?".

Comment: I am using windows. I am having a hard time finding a module that will allow me to change the settings for the microphone: Listen to this device or mute unmute. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @lawre6b3 could you please accept one of the answers if any of them worked for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This can easily be achieved by using [PyWin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

```py
import win32api
import win32gui

WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319
APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x180000

hwnd_active = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd_active, WM_APPCOMMAND, None, APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE)
```

Unlike the name `APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE` would suggest, this actually toggles the mic

`mute` → `unmute` | `unmute` → `mute`

Here is a list of other useful parameters that can be used with `WM_APPCOMMAND`: [WM_APPCOMMAND message (Winuser.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand#parameters)

Comment: is there something similar for mac?

Answer (score 1):

[PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) is one cross-platform option for this. It's more than just direct access to the audio device controls, so it's moderately complicated to use. [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/docs/pymedia.audio.sound.html) is another option, the `pymedia.audio.sound` package provides access to the mixer devices which is where the controls for the microphone (input level, mute etc.) would be.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution to this, if you have Windows, is to download Windows PowerToys, run it as an administrator, turn on Video Conference mute, and VOILA, Win button + Shift + A will mute you.

There's an option to turn off your camera with a keyboard shortcut, too. And you can do both at the same time if you like.

Sometimes python isn't the right answer :)