# How to mute microphone for Cross-Platform?

Tags: python, cross-platform

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549391/how-to-toggle-microphone-on-and-off-using-python).

But there isn't a clear way to go on how to mute microphone cross-platform (Mac+Windows).

I need this for building a DIY physical button with a raspberry pi 0 for muting/unmuting Zoom/Teams calls.

I have tried combing pymedia and pyaudio documentation without luck.